# C++ substring/ string manipulation

Tags: c++, string

I've been building a shell for a while now, and I decided to implement the echo function. However, no matter how much I tried, it returned nothing (literally, nothing. Just blank.). I looked through a ton of different references, but most strings did not include a space, mine typically will.

Edit: The globals, are, indeed, pointless, and were put there to make it easier to copy/paste directly into the shell I was writing, which relied heavily on them.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
static string argument;

string echo(string echoarg)
{
    string echoreturn = echoarg.substr(4);
    return echoreturn;
}

int main()
{
    string argument;
    cin >> argument;
    cout << echo(argument);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `echoarg` is not initialized with any values.

Comment: Both of the globals are pointless.

Comment: What exactly are you passing in?

Comment: @aliasm2k value will be passed to it via echo function.

Answer (score 6):

No, your string won't include a space, because `cin >>` stops at the first space.

Try

```
getline(cin, argument);
```

instead.